# How to extract value

Tags: python, api, pandas

i have called following data from the quantopian api and received following data:

```
{Equity(25600, symbol=u'LPHI', asset_name=u'LIFE PARTNERS HOLDINGS INC', exchange=u'NASDAQ', start_date=Timestamp('2003-10-21 00:00:00+0000', tz='UTC'), end_date=Timestamp('2015-03-27 00:00:00+0000', tz='UTC'), first_traded=None, auto_close_date=Timestamp('2015-04-01 00:00:00+0000', tz='UTC'), exchange_full=u'NASDAQ GLOBAL SELECT MARKET'): [Event({'status': 0, 'created': Timestamp('2010-04-01 13:31:00+0000', tz='UTC'), 'limit_reached': False, 'stop': None, 'reason': None, 'stop_reached': False, 'commission': 0, 'amount': 8923, 'limit': None, 'sid': Equity(25600, symbol=u'LPHI', asset_name=u'LIFE PARTNERS HOLDINGS INC', exchange=u'NASDAQ', start_date=Timestamp('2003-10-21 00:00:00+0000', tz='UTC'), end_date=Timestamp('2015-03-27 00:00:00+0000', tz='UTC'), first_traded=None, auto_close_date=Timestamp('2015-04-01 00:00:00+0000', tz='UTC'), exchange_full=u'NASDAQ GLOBAL SELECT MARKET'), 'dt': Timestamp('2010-04-01 13:31:00+0000', tz='UTC'), 'id': 'effc428d025c4bf69ec59cd6f225d8a7', 'filled': 0})]}
```

Now i only need the first number of the data. In this case it is the 25600
Can you guys let me know how i can extract it ?

Thanks a lot and kind regards

Comment: what is the datatype? will the call always come in this format?

Comment: i dont know to be honest

Comment: `print(type('YOUR_API_CALL_HERE'))`

Answer (score 3):

A dirty way to do this is

```
s = a.find('Equity') # where a is your string you get from quantopian

e = a.find('symbol')

print(a[s+7:e-2])
```

I find the indices of `Equity` and `Symbol` and then just get whatever is in the middle using the slicing operator after appropriate indexing.

you can cast the return value from quantopian to a string by using `str(response)` to perform the indexing